# Is it possible to filter an absolute path from Apache ErrorLog?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost

Using **Apache** is it possible to edit the **Virtual Host** to exclude a certain **absolute path** (such as `/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/`) from log to the `ErrorLog` file?

I need to stop it from log warnings like this:

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/tool.php
```

However I need to see other warnings, it's only about one file that's the reason why I would like to keep my `php.ini` unaltered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error message comes from php framework and mod_php, so the answer is no.

If you don't want to see them in httpd you will have to separate them (interpret php with php-fpm and proxy requests to it through mod_proxy_fcgi).

Apache httpd has no control over error messages generated by mod_php, so you do have to change php.ini or the above option, which I recommend (separation).